# Delete facl for unnamed user

Tags: linux, acl

I accidentally setfacl's for an empty user so that all of my facl's have an unnamed user at the top:

```
# file: test.txt
# owner: friend
# group: kevinburke
user::rw-
user:friend:rwx
user:kevinburke:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
```

How can I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the `user::rw-` entry, then these are permissions for the owner (here `friend`) and you obviously cannot delete this. Same for the `group::r-x` and `other::---` entries